# Create external user with simple-salesforce

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I want to create an external user because I want to send a confirmation email once user is created, but I don't find the way to do this with simple-salesforce.

I have seen that with APEX class Site it is possible to do (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm?search_text=site).

How can I do that? Is there any other way to do it?

```
import json
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce, SalesforceLogin, SFType

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    session_id='session'
    instance='instance'
    sf = Salesforce(instance=instance, session_id=session_id)
    
    sftype_user = SFType('User', session_id, instance)
    
    params={
        "Username": "user@username.com",
        "FirstName": "User",
        "LastName": "Test",
        "Email": "user@username.com",
        "Alias": "user",
        "TimeZoneSidKey": "Europe/Berlin",
        "LocaleSidKey": "es_ES",
        "EmailEncodingKey": "ISO-8859-1",
        "ProfileId": "profileid",
        "LanguageLocaleKey":"es"
    }
    user = sftype_user.createUser(params)

    String userId = Site.createExternalUser(user, None, None, True)
    print(userId)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Simple" uses REST API. As far as I know there's no REST API call that would correspond to Apex's Site class methods.

You should be able to use the normal user creation call, just pass the `ContactId` and right community-related `ProfileId` in it. If you hit any problems - edit the question?

Or try to write a piece of Apex code that works for you and expose it as a [REST service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm) and call that from Python. Useful especially if you'll have to eventually do more with the user, maybe make him a group member, maybe assign some permission sets... You'd want that to be an all-or-none transaction, not wasting separate API calls.